# sort tasks by number of stars odoo11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I have a field selection with 3 level:

```
priority = fields.Selection([('0','Low'), ('1','Normal'), ('2','High'), ('3', 'Very High')], 'Priority'),
```

In `xml` form and kanban view:

```
<field name="priority" widget="priority"/>
```

When I put task as very high (3 stars) on kanban view, I should refresh the browser to re-order the tasks (standard odoo).

Now I would to re-order the tasks in kanban view without refresh the browser.

Comment: In your python model, try to add the attribute ``_order = 'priority DESC'`` (just under ``_name`` or ``_inherit``

Comment: The model has it already  _order = "priority desc, sequence, id desc". it works after refreshing the browser. It should work immediately